# Binding two lists into one data grid view

Tags: c#

So I have two lists (`Members` and `RealEstate`)

I want my `DataGridView` to display results of the `MemberID` that was written in a text box I have.

Results include:

- `MemberID`, `FirstName` from the `Members` List and
- `EstateType`, `EstatePrice`, `EstateArea` from the `RealEstate` List

My code is as follows :

```
List<Members> member = FrmSell.MembersList.FindAll(owner => owner.MemberID == int.Parse(FrmSell.txt));
List<RealEstate> realestate = FrmSell.EstateList;
dgvProperty.DataSource = member;
dgvProperty.DataSource = realestate;
```

And when I click on my button it only displays the results from the second list which is the `RealEstate` list and not the first one, I want to display results from both lists combined into a single data grid view.

If you need any more clarification please do tell me.

Sample data from the list :

```
//Sample data
Members m1 = new Members(001,"Ahmed","Muhairy",503299999);
MembersList.Add(new Members(002,"Khalfan","AlMarri",502344556));

RealEstate r1 = new RealEstate("Villa",35000,"Quoz",4,2);
EstateList.Add(new RealEstate("House",55000,"Sharjah",6,4));
```

Comment: What do you suppose the value of the `dgvProperty.DataSource` is in your code? Could that explain what you are observing?

Comment: where is the information stored where you are trying to fill the Members and RealEstate..? if the information is stored in a database.. then I would recommend / suggest you write a query to return the data..then use a dataset or datatable to bind the data to the datagrid also do some reading and research on the DataGridView's DataSource property..

Comment: im not sure whether this answers your questions, but the information in those lists are stored in class files (RealEstate.cs and Members.Cs)

Comment: Edited the OP with sample data from the lists

Comment: you need to do some reading on how to bind a List<T> to a datagrid also read up and understand how binding works as well as what the DataSource property means...

Comment: How are members related to real estate? I don't see how you can match a member (using e.g. the `MemberID` field value) with an instance of `RealEstate` from the `EstateList`.

Comment: the OP needs to understand how keys work and RealEstate has not related keys, start looking at learning database and sql and understand the term `Relationship` I am voting to close this question further more learn to use the debugger.. and step through the code and you will quickly see what you are or are not doing correctly.. what not create a Class Memebers..then with the Members after creating a RealEstate Class.. create a List<RealEstate> object inside your Members Class

Comment: @MethodMan, if OP can answer the question how the two lists are related, this is still salvageable.

Comment: Why can't you use a `Dicitionary` or `KeyValuePair` rather than a `List`.  Simply copy your existing `List` into the `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Greg possibly but I cannot see any relationship but I think we would need to hear from the OP first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to combine the fields from the matching entries in the two lists into either a `DataSet` or `DataTable`, or into a list of items of a new class that contains the fields from both input types.

For this to work, there must be a field in either the `Member` or `RealEstate` class that allows matching up the entries from both input lists.

As an example, I am going to assume the following: your `RealEstate` class has an `OwnerID` field, whose value identifies one of the members in the `MembersList`, because it is equal to the member's `MemberID` value.

Now you can do the following:

```
// This combines the fields from Member and RealEstate
// for a row to be displayed in the data grid.
public class MemberRealEstate
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public int EstateID { get; set; }
    public string EstateType { get; set; }
    public double EstatePrice { get; set; }
    public string EstateArea { get; set; }
}
```

And create a new list, combining entries from the other two:

```
var forMemberId = int.Parse(FrmSell.txt);
var memberRealEstateList = 
    (from estate in FrmSell.EstateList
     from member in FrmSell.MembersList
     where member.MemberID == forMemberId && member.MemberID == estate.OwnerID
     select new MemberRealEstate() {
         MemberID  = member.MemberID,
         MemberName = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName,
         EstateID = estate.EstateID,
         EstateType = estate.EstateType,
         EstatePrice = estate.EstatePrice,
         EstateArea  = estate.EstateArea 
     }).ToList();
```

Now you can assign this list as the `DataSource` for your `DataGridView`:

```
dgvProperty.DataSource = memberRealEstateList;
```

Comment: Your assumption was exactly correct. However, must I create a new class?, is there no other way where I can use the 2 classes I already created?

Comment: No, you can't use those two directly, you need a class that "joins" the fields you need in your new list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209825/how-to-combine-multiple-lists-and-use-as-a-gridview-datasource#34210098 Please help